# How to return object explicitly in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

This works:

```
myfunc = () ->
    id: 3
    name: 'myname'
```

But I want to be explicit about returning object.

```
myfunc = () ->
    return
        id: 3
        name: 'myname'
```

But I get "Unexpected 'INDENT'" error. What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: See https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1263.

Comment: you’re better off not to explicitly return it, as coffeescript always implictitly returns stuff. explicitly doing it is not only redundant, but might trick the reader into believing it makes a difference and functions without explicit return value would return `undefined` like in JS.

Comment: @flyingsheep "not only redundant, but might trick the reader into believing it makes a difference" That is such a critical point and is applicable to so many different.

Comment: You shouldn't assume everyone is an idiot. Experienced CoffeeScript users often use explicit return statements. Personally, I only use implicit returns with functions that have a single expression as their body, which is a popular approach. Not using a language feature because you assume people will be confused by something this basic is a recipe for some truly awful code.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
myFunc = ->
  return {
    id   : 3
    name : 'myname'
  }

myFunc = ->
  return {} =
    id   : 3
    name : 'myname'

myFunc = ->
  # return
  id   : 3
  name : 'myname'
```

Comment: I esp. like the last one ;-)

Comment: yeah 3rd is awesome / hilarious

Comment: I like the second one.

Answer (score 10):

you should put the return value on the same line or wrap it in `()` :

```
myFunc = () ->
  return id:3, name:'myname'

myFunc = () ->
  return (
    id: 3
    name: 'myname'
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is

```
myFunc = ->
  return (
    id: 3
    name: 'myname'
  )
```

because it fits the philosophy of functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are all correct.  This works too:

```
myFunc = () -> 
    {
        id: 3
        name: 'myname'
    }
```